# using passport-jwt in nest with secretOrKeyProvider option keep responsing http 401?

Tags: nestjs, passport.js, firebase-admin, passport-jwt, nestjs-passport

I am a new coder with nestjs, I want to use passport-jwt , nestjs/passport and firebase to build my app's authetication part, below are my codes. But I just got http 401 response, how can i fix it ?

here is my strategy:

```js
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase-admin/auth';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'firebase') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKeyProvider: async (request, rawJwtToken, done) => {
        try {
          const decodedToken = await getAuth().verifyIdToken(rawJwtToken);
          done(null, decodedToken);
        } catch (error) {
          done(error);
        }
      },
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    console.log('validate');
    return payload;
  }
}
```

here is my guard:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('firebase') {}
```

here is my auth.module.ts:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { UsersModule } from '../users/users.module';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { FirebaseStrategy } from './firebase.stragety';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';

@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  imports: [UsersModule, PassportModule, JwtModule.register({})],
  providers: [AuthService, FirebaseStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

and here is my controller:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Request, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { FirebaseAuthGuard } from './firebase.guard';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  @UseGuards(FirebaseAuthGuard)
  @Get('login')
  async logIn(@Request() req) {
    return 'login';
  }
}
```

I just found my validate method in FirebaseStrategy not invoked, it should be invoked everytime when secretOrKeyProvider verified jwt in http header, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 401 with no call of the `validate` method of your `JwtStrategy` that means that for some reason passport is reading the `JWT` you send as invalid. To find the specific reason for it you can modify your `FirebaseAuthGuard` to have the following `handleRequest` method, which will log out extra details

```js
handleRequest(err, user, info, context, status) {
  console.log({ err, user, info, context, status });
  return super.handleRequest(err, user, info, context, status);
}
```

As mentioned, this will print out what error or info passport is reading and throwing for, and will allow you to properly adjust your JWT/know to refresh it/change it because of invalid signature/whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

The callback definition `secretOrKeyProvider` is used to return the secret that is required to verify the JWT. It is not intended to verify the JWT in this callback, see also here: https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/

The validation of the JWT should be done an a validate function, so move your `await getAuth().verifyIdToken(rawJwtToken);` into a validate function. I use it normally like this:

```js
  async validate(payload: any) {
    console.log('validate');
    let user;
    if (payload) {
      this.logger.debug('Received a normal access token, check access token.');
      user = await this.usersService.validateJwtPayload(payload);
    }

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedError();
    }
    return user;
  }
```

In the validateJwtPayload I e.g. lookup the user and ensure the user was not deativated in the meantime, save a lastSeenAt timestamp for the user in the database. If the user is inactivated or payload.username does not exist return there undefined which will then block access.